# CRUD menu creation

Tags: c#, winforms, crud

I would like to re-write this C# code so it is easier to understand. Should I create a separate function to configure a menu item? Is there is some kind of `using` statement so I only need to mention the menu name once?

```
private void initializeContextMenuRightClick()
    {
        try
        {
            ctxMenuStripRightClick = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ctxMenuStripRightClick.Opening += ctxMenuStrip_Opening;

            ToolStripMenuItem addMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add", null, AddMenuItem_Click);
            ToolStripMenuItem deleteMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete", null, DeleteMenuItem_Click);
            ToolStripMenuItem editMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Edit", null, EditMenuItem_Click);
            ToolStripMenuItem markDoneMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Mark Done", null, MarkDoneMenuItem_Click);
            ToolStripSeparator separatorMenuItem = new ToolStripSeparator();

            ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(addMenuItem);

            ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(deleteMenuItem);
            ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(editMenuItem);
            ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(separatorMenuItem);
            ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(markDoneMenuItem);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException.Show(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the intermediate tool menu variables?  Could you not just use ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Add", null, AddMenuItem_Click)) etc

Comment: Good idea.  Is there a way I can avoid repeatedly mentioning ctxMenuStripRightClick ?

Comment: Yes, see my answer as a bit much for a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can avoid repeatedly mentioning
>   ctxMenuStripRightClick.

Yes, I guess you could do something like:

```
ctxMenuStripRightClick = new ContextMenuStrip();
ctxMenuStripRightClick.Opening += ctxMenuStrip_Opening;
ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.AddRange(new List<ToolStripMenuItem>
{
    new ToolStripMenuItem("Add", null, AddMenuItem_Click),
    new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete", null, DeleteMenuItem_Click),
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create new function to add item

```
private void AddMenuItem(string caption, EventHandler onClick) {
    ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(
        new ToolStripMenuItem(caption, null, onClick)
    );    
}
```

So your initialization method will be

```
ctxMenuStripRightClick = new ContextMenuStrip();
ctxMenuStripRightClick.Opening += ctxMenuStrip_Opening;
AddMenuItem("Add", AddMenuItem_Click);
AddMenuItem("Delete", DeleteMenuItem_Click);
AddMenuItem("Edit", EditMenuItem_Click);
ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
AddMenuItem("Mark Done", MarkDoneMenuItem_Click);
```

EDIT: If you really don't want a separated function, you can use lambda expression:

```
Action<string, EventHandler> addMenuItem = (caption, onClick) =>
{
    ctxMenuStripRightClick.Items.Add(
        new ToolStripMenuItem(caption, null, onClick)
    );
};
addMenuItem("Add", AddMenuItem_Click);
...
```

Comment: i like the separate function idea, but I want ctxMenuStripRightClick to be private to the main procedure

Comment: @kirsteng See my update.